# no update on sql server database. No errors just no results

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
//the @Question column name needs to change according to the checkbox. For example Checkbox1 - Question1

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...);
String sql = "UPDATE INQUIRY2 set @Question = @str WHERE email = @email AND base = @base;";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
con.Open();

    //checkbox2 - question 2
    //if (CheckBox3.Checked == true)
    //{
      //  str = str + CheckBox3 + 'x';
    //}


    DataTable theDataTable = null;

       // Verify that dt is actually in session before trying to get it

        if(Session["dt"] != null)
        {
            theDataTable = Session["dt"] as DataTable;
        }

    //Verify that the data table is not null
    if(theDataTable != null)
    {
        email = theDataTable.Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
        base1 = theDataTable.Rows[0]["base"].ToString();

    }
    //checkbox1 - question 1
    if (CheckBox9.Checked == true)
    {
        str = str + CheckBox9.Text + 'x';
        strQuestOne = theDataTable.Columns["Question1"].ToString();

    }


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", str);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", strQuestOne);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@base", base1);


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Most probably your Session["dt"] returns null - have you tried debugging ? :)

Comment: I ran the debug and got a NullReferenceException was unhandled... at the strQuestone = theDataTable.Columns line

Comment: You omitted your connection string, and didn't really describe the problem very well, but I'll throw out another potential suspect: you're using `AttachDbFileName` in your connection string. Oh yeah, and you can't parameterize a column name anyway (+1 to @fcuesta).

Answer (score 3):

You are using a parameter for a column name. Database objects (columns names, tables, stored procedures or any other objects) cannot be passed as parameters. Only actual values for columns or variables can be parameters. You need to build your SQL statement dynamically in this case:

```
String sql ="UPDATE INQUIRY2 set " + strQuestOne + "= @str WHERE email = ...
```

But now you should be carefull because you code is at risk of SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL uses @param type in the string.

If you are looking to execute a stored procedure of some sort to negate most sql injection attacks on a website you might want to consider calling a stored procedure and adding SqlCommand.Parameter to the SqlCommand.Parameters Collection.

Otherwise if you want to just execute the sql you should do

string sql = String.Format("UPDATE TABLE set COLUMN = {0} where OTHERCOLUMN = {1}", varValue, varWhere);